# How is : Date.parse("123 456 789") == Fri, 03 May 2019?

Tags: ruby

The title pretty much says it all.  I'm trying to assess the validity of dates from a CSV import but if someone chooses a telephone number column for date of birth the Date parsing still passes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation on [`Date#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) explicitly states:

> This method does not function as a validator.

That means, this method is omnivorous, it’ll produce a date from whatever input. You need to use [`Date#iso8601`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-iso8601) instead:

```
main > Date.iso8601("2019-03-19")
#⇒ #<Date: 2019-03-19 ((2458562j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
main > Date.iso8601("123 456 789")
#⇒ ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Comment: My issue with Date.io8601 is that I can only check "yyyy-mm-dd".  I potentially have dates coming in as "19/03/2019", "19th March 2019", "19-3-2019" and so on.  Is there a way to check validity for all types?

Comment: Then use `Date#_parse` as proposed by @Stefan and ensure all `:year`, `:month` and `:day` are there.

Comment: @Mark, as Aleksei (aka 'mudsie') says, Ruby cannot tell you whether a string represents a date. That's some you must do. The most sure-fire way is to compile that list and then write something like `d = (Date.strptime('19/03/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')  rescue nil) || (Date.strptime('19-3-2019', '%d-%-m-%Y')  rescue nil) || ...`. See [Date::strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) for formatting directives.

Comment: Aleksei, that's an interesting idea (your comment), but what about `Date._parse('1 2 2019') => {:mon=>20, :mday=>19}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I doubt `'1 2 2019'` should be treated as a valid input, but if it should one might do `Date._parse('1 2 2019'.tr(' ', '-'))` which is relatively safe.

Comment: What is `01/02/03`? Is that `YY/MM/DD` or `DD/MM/YY` or `MM/DD/YY`? These omnivorous consumers take a wild guess without coaching and may be wrong.

Comment: @tadman, methinks that requires the OP to make an assumption or enforce a rule.

Comment: I agree @CarySwoveland, I think I'll have to assume formats and not leave it so open.

Answer (score 6):

> How is : Date.parse(“123 456 789”) == Fri, 03 May 2019?

[`Date._parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-_parse) (with an underscore) returns the raw data:

```
Date._parse('123 456 789')
#=> {:yday=>123}
```

Ruby treats `123` as the day of the year and the 123rd day of the current year is May 3.

Comment: `Date::parse` is especially useful for extracting hidden date information in strings: `Date._parse("When should 'can' be used instead of 'may'?") #=> {:mon=>5} `. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You (and possibly others) might find the following method useful. I've made the following assumptions:

- years must be four digits;
- invalid commas can be disregarded and removed (e.g., "Jan, 3 2019"); and
- the day of the week can be disregarded and removed, even if it is invalid for the date.

```
MON_NAMES = Date::MONTHNAMES.drop(1).concat(Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.drop(1))
  #=> ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  #    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December",
  #    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  #    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] 
MON_REGEX = /\b#{Regexp.union(MON_NAMES)}\b(?!\A)/
  # => /\b(?-mix:January|February|...|December|Jan|Feb|...|Dec)\b(?!\A)/ 
MONTH_STR_TO_NBR = MON_NAMES.each_with_index.map { |mon,i| [mon, " #{1 + (i%12)} "] }.to_h 
  #=> {"January"=>" 1 ", "February"=>" 2 ", ... , "December"=>" 12 ",
  #    "Jan"=>" 1 ", "Feb"=>" 2 ", ... , "Dec"=>" 12 "} 
DAY_REGEX = /\b#{Regexp.union(Date::DAYNAMES + Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES)}\b,?/
  #=> /\b(?-mix:Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat)\b,?/
```

```
def my_parse(date_str, locale = :US)
  a = date_str.gsub(MON_REGEX, MONTH_STR_TO_NBR).
               gsub(DAY_REGEX, '').
               gsub(/(?<!\p{Alpha})(?:st|rd|th|,)(?!\p{Alpha})/, '').
               gsub(/[-\/]/, ' ').
               strip.
               split
  return nil if a.size != 3 || a.any? { |s| s.match?(/\D/) }
  yr_idx = a.index { |s| s.size == 4 }
  return nil if yr_idx.nil? || yr_idx == 1
  yr = a.delete_at(yr_idx)
  return nil unless a.all? { |s| [1,2].include? s.size }
  if yr_idx == 0
    mon, day = a
  else
    mon, day = locale == :US ? a : a.reverse
  end
  begin
    Date.strptime("%s %s %s" % [mon, day, yr], '%m %d %Y')
  rescue ArgumentError
    nil
  end
end
```

```
my_parse("Tue, 12th January 2019")      #=> #<Date: 2019-01-12 (...)> 
my_parse("Tue, 12th January 2019", :UK) #=> #<Date: 2019-12-01 (...)> 
my_parse("12/4/2019", :US)              #=> #<Date: 2019-04-12 (...)>
my_parse("12/4/2019", :UK)              #=> #<Date: 2019-12-04 (...)>
my_parse("Jan 12, 2019")                #=> #<Date: 2019-12-01 (...)>
my_parse("2019 Jan 23rd")               #=> #<Date: 2019-01-23 (...)> 
my_parse("Jan 2019 4")                  #=> nil 
my_parse("1/2019/4")                    #=> nil 
my_parse("1/2019/4")                    #=> nil    
my_parse("Jen 12, 2019")                #=> nil 
my_parse("3 Jan 12, 2019")              #=> nil
```

I would encourage readers to identify any other assumptions required that I have not mentioned. This could of course be modified as needed. One change that could be made fairly easily would be to confirm that the day of week, if present, is correct for the given date.

Comment: I cannot help but wonder if there is a gem that does this and more.